# Integration of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 & TFS 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm going reflect updates from TFS in MS CRM. In what way I could connect them?

I've found this tool: http://www.quantumwhisper.com/dynamics-crm-microsoft-tfs-integration/.

Are there any other tools like this one or possibly other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Shan over at ADX is pretty much paving the way on this.  Really great stuff, but I'm unsure what ADX keeps internal versus releasing to the community.

http://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-alm-toolkit/